# has_many and belongs_to association to same model using different keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have two models in my rails application

```
    Class Employee 
      belongs_to :cost_center
    End

    Class CostCenter
      has_many :employees
    End
```

Now an employee can **have many cost centers** as a **cost center owner**. How do I define this association in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the correct columns, but otherwise it's easy.

```
class Employee
  has_many :owned_cost_centers, :class_name => "CostCenter", :foreign_key => :owner_id
  belongs_to :cost_center
end

class CostCenter
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => :owner_id
  has_many :employees
end
```

For completeness, you should add `:inverse_of` to all associations.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid having a circular reference.  If an employee belongs to a cost center, then an owner should belong to a cost center as well.

If you really needed to distinguish between owning and being employed, I would consider making two models, since an employee is a different entity to an owner.

```
class Owner
  belongs_to :cost_center
end

class CostCenter
  has_many employees
  has_one owner
end
```